# Washing a Shaitel - Wig during the three weeks

Tags: halacha, hair-covering, three-weeks

This past week a lady told my wife that it is forbidden to wash a Shaitel - Wig during the three weeks. To the best of my knowledge I have never seen such a prohibition. Is there a source that prohibits washing a wig during the three weeks?

Comment: Cutting it for the first time is probably assur in 9 days as tikun begadim. If in fact it was never cut, there is a strong possibility she never made a shehechiyanu on it which is a bracha to be avoided in the three weeks. That's probably the most stringent you'll get. There is no reason to think a wig is actual hair (which would only preclude it being washed during the 9 days). I mean she's not running out of an ir hanidachas, right?

Comment: Check out this article http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/735559/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/halachos-of-the-three-weeks/ especially 5c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a single instance of a Posek forbidding washing or laundering 
 anything during the (first 2 weeks of the) 3 weeks.

<sup>I searched the Shulchan Aruch, Kitzur SA, Kitzur Yalkut Yosef and Aruch HaShulchan</sup>

Even during the 9 days (or the week during which Tish'a B'Av falls, as per the Sefardim) when most laundering is forbidden, clothes that get soiled often and one has a finite supply - like cloth diapers - may be washed. 
Similarly, anything a woman needs for her 7-clean days may be laundered, as a Mitzvah trumps the custom of not washing.
I would venture to say that if a woman is in the habit of washing her wig every few days because it gets very sweaty, for example, then she may be allowed to do so even during the 9 days since she can't be expected to have a wig collection.

> וְאִשָּׁה שֶׁצְּרִיכָה לִלְבּוֹשׁ לְבָנִים לִסְפֹּר ז' נְקִיִּים, מֻתֶּרֶת לְכַבֵּס וְלִלְבּוֹשׁ
> וְכֵן הַמִּטְפָּחוֹת שֶׁמְלַפְּפִין בָּהֶן אֶת הַתִּינוֹקוֹת [חִתּוּלִים], שֶׁמְלַכְלְכִין אוֹתָן תָּדִיר, מֻתָּר לְכַבְּסָ
>   
> - Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 122:9

Comment: Your logic sounds reasonable, except that underwear and diapers don't have substitutes to do the same job. A woman, OTOH, can cover her hair with a tichel, snood (Are you trying to ruin my sister-in-law's sub-business? She sells snoods, and I think the 9 Days brings in some increased business!) , or hat. There's nothing that says that she must wear a shaitel.