# Cutting a wig during the 3 weeks

Tags: three-weeks

Can someone cut their wig (peah nachris) during the 3 weeks? Do we consider the wig to be hair or do we consider it to be a beged of some sort?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84106/washing-a-shaitel-wig-during-the-three-weeks

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38186/what-types-of-hair-and-whose-hair-are-included-in-mourning-related-hair-cutt/38223#38223

Answer (score 2):

[This (Hebrew) article](https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=21396) quotes Rav Shmuel Vosner ZTL as saying that washing and setting a wig is like washing and ironing clothes and is thus only forbidden during the (9) days just before Tisha B'Av, and cutting a wig is permitted [and is not considered like cutting hair].

Answer (score 1):

Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky quoted in קובץ הלכות בין המצרים י"ג/הערה י"א says that it is like a garment, and not like a haircut. He does not understand Rav Moshe, who says that it is like a haircut.

אמר מו"ר שליט"א דאע"ג שאין גילוח פאה נכרית חשיב גילוח ממש אפ"ה ודאי אית בי' משום תיקון בגדים שהוא נתחדש ע"י הגילוח ואסור מטעם זה עכ"ד. וראיתי ספר זכרון שלמה הל' חוה"מ תשובות הגר"מ פיינשטיין זצ"ל סקי"ד, שהאג"מ הורה שבחוה"מ אסור לגלח פאה נכרית משום שזה בכלל גזירת גילוח, ולכאו' ה"ה בנידו"ד באופן שלכאו' יהא אסור לגלח פאה נכרית במשך כל ימי בין המצרים. ומו"ר שליט"א אמר שזה חידוש גדול להחשיב גילוח הפאה כגילוח ממש וצ"ע.

Comment: It's intresting to note that Rav Shmuel doesnt say its not considerd haricuting at all,rather he says its not mamash haircutting.

Comment: @sam - I should point out, that Rav Shmuel is talking about the nine days, not the three weeks. It still answers your question if it is a garment or a haircut. As far as your point. I would understand it as saying "even though it's not a actual haircut, it is forbidden [in the nine days] because of fixing garments".